# How to add mouseenter listener to control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, devextreme

I am creating HTML controls with this kind of code

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().Button()
    .ID("submitButton")
    .Text("Submit")
    .Icon("check")
    .Type(ButtonType.Success)
)
```

How can I add a mouse enter listener?

There exist `.OnInitialized` and `.OnContentReady`, also `.OnKeyDown` `.OnInput` etc., but no `.OnMouseEnter` for example.

> 'SelectBoxBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'OnMouseEnter' and no accessible extension method ... could be found

How can I call some javascript function for mouseover or mouseenter? Generating some equivalent of the HTML

```
<input onmouseenter="myFunction()">
```

---

I can probably use `.OnInitialized("addMouseEnter")` but is there a cleaner way to do it with less in-betweens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out about `.ElementAttr` which can be used to add element attributes manually.

```
    .ElementAttr("onmouseenter", "myFunction()")`
```

works for this case